# php simplxml - Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So I'm getting an error trying to access player name in an XML File using the code. I'm not sure if i'm accessing the information right is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('trueskill.bcn');

$playername = $xml->SK92->Players[0]->Name;

echo $playername;
?>
```

Using the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SK92>
  <Settings Multiplier="200" Decay="0" />
  <Players>
    <Player Name="Mark" Team="" Invisible="false" Characters="" Alts="JFG;Mark;SEBA" />
    <Player Name="Antonio" Team="" Invisible="false" Characters="" Alts="Proxy;Toni" />
  </Players>
</SK92>
```

Comment: Remove the `->SK92`. Hope that does the trick? Also normally a `xml` file ends with `*.xml`

Comment: nope nothing. I have a program that outputs xml data as a BCN file. The program reads bcn but its basically xml data

Comment: The mistake you've made is common. And has been asked & answered about earlier. Please use the search first (the duplicate directly appears by entering your questions title into google btw.).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $xml->Players->Player['Name'];
```

should do the trick.

To have it in variables:

```
$playername = $xml->Players->Player['Name'];
echo $playername;
```

---

SIDENOTE:

As I suppose you want to access all the players, you can do this by:

```
foreach ($xml->Players->Player as $play) {
    echo $play['Name'] . "<br>\n";
}
```